# Cannot read property 'className' of null

Tags: javascript

This isn't working. I have an element in my html with the id "color". What is the deal? I just want it to add to the class of that element.

```
var el = document.getElementById("color");
var number = Math.floor((Math.random() * 5) + 1);

switch (number) {
    case 1:
        el.className += " blue";
        break;

    case 2:
        el.className += " yellow";
        break;

    case 3:
        el.className += " red";
        break;

    case 4:
        el.className += " green";
        break;

    case 5:
        el.className += " purple";
        break;
}
```

Comment: Is the script executed before the document has loaded?

Comment: Are you running this before the DOM is loaded?

Answer (score 9):

I'd say this comes from the fact the body is not loaded when you try to get the `#color` element.

Just wrap the thing inside this

```
window.onload = function () {
    // your code
};
```

Or you can load your code at the end of the body

```
<body>
    <!-- you content -->
    <script src="your-script.js"></script>
</body>
```

And finally you can listen for the `DOMContentLoaded` event. It's a little faster than window.onload but has slightly less support, IE9+.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
  // your code
});
```

Comment: @Jonathan Good suggestion, though I could have updated my answer had you commented :p

Comment: On a page with a lot of images, hooking into DOMContentLoaded event is actually a lot faster than onLoad.

Comment: Or by convention include your js at the end, before </body>

Comment: @argentum47 This is what is already stated in my answer, actually

Comment: my mistake. didn't see that.

Answer (score 0):

I declared a variable "el" that wasn't within the scope of the switch.